# Does newer node version support yarn?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I can see following message on the log of circle-ci:

```
yarn install v1.1.0
```

> warning You are using Node "9.3.0" which is not supported and may
>   encounter bugs or unexpected behavior. Yarn supports the following
>   semver range: "^4.8.0 || ^5.7.0 || ^6.2.2 || ^8.0.0"

Does this means that yarn is outdated and  "npm" should be used instead?

Comment: You can ignore those warnings. See https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4837

Comment: thanks, but what is best current practice? to use npm?

Comment: Comparing yarn and npm is off topic here. It's too much opinion based and it's clearly not a stable conclusion as both tools are changing a lot.

Comment: My team has a  long debate about which tool to choose, after  some time we decided to select yarn. Because i was one of yarn supporters, i'm very glad to see that the choice wasnt totally wrong. Thanks